# How to store data locally?

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-storage, analytics

I am building web analytics tools which deal with tracking the `click events and mouse movements`, For this, I don't want to send the data to the server for every `mouse move` or `click`, instead I planned to save locally and send the data to the server at session time out or while closing the browser or tab (closing the web site).

**Note:** Large amount of data is to be stored locally.

I know some possible ways to store the data locally.

```
 1.LocalStorage:
      Drawbacks:  Domain Specific so i can't rely on this.

 2.Cookie
     Drawbacks: 1.Analytics fails if cookie is disabled
                2.Not possible to store large amount of data
                     (scenario: Every mouse movement 
                      co-ordinates should be captured)
```

I have two questions:

1.Whether storing data locally is good practice (specifically with web analytics)?

2.Is there any other possible ways of storing `large amount` (cannot assume) of data   locally?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/

Comment: What event are you using, onbeforeunload? you should probably read this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138411/catching-a-tab-close-event-in-web-browser#answer-4319352

Answer (score 1):

At least Safari and Chrome have a Web SQL Database API so you'll be able to use sqlite instead of raw local storage. I found a good **[article about sqlite usage in web browser](http://rickosborne.org/blog/2010/03/html5-in-browser-sql-database-storage/)**.

An other option would be to keep your data straight in memory (and push it to the server when a certain size is reached).