# How to call window.unload

Tags: javascript, dom-events, window.onunload

I am using web socket connection for communication. But when user refresh page, I want to close this web socket connection.
I also using `window.onbeforeunload` event to show confirmation box to user with customized text. If user selects 'do not reload' option then no action (which is working fine)
But I want to close web socket connection if user selects reload option. I don't know how to achieve this. I tried to call `window.unload` and tried to close web socket connection but its not working. My code is as follows.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
     return "you are closing this web page';
};

           
window.unload = function(e) {
     webSockect.closeConnection();
};
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Window events are prefixed with `on`.

Try to use `window.onunload = ...` or even better

`window.addEventListener('unload', ...)`.

When using `addEventListener` you specify the event name without `on` prefix.

Read more: [WindowEventHandlers.onunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers.onunload)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a syntax error in the code above, you have written:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
     return "you are closing this web page';
};
```

So, type of quotes there should be either single or double, same at start and end of the string.

It is supposed to be, and it will work:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return "you are closing this web page";
};
```

====

Back to the point. All you can do with unload prompt is to change the Message. Anything otherwise doesn't work like:

- Changing the action on Buttons on the prompt
- Changing the Button text of the prompt
- Changing the UI of the box

Q. even you write something before the `return` if the **function**, that will be ignored by the browser.

Comment: Window.unload function is not supported by all browsers, so onBeforeUnload function is better.

Also you can find list of events when this function is triggered: [OnBeforeUnload - Event List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138411/catching-a-tab-close-event-in-web-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact run a method on close if you assign the method to a variable and then return the variable.

```
function unloadWebSocket()
{
    webSockect.closeConnection();
}

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) 
{
    var x = unloadWebSocket();
    return x;
};
```

While I have no experience with websockets, I know this works with synchronous ajax requests.